# Lint: Release build fails after deleting an unused resource

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I deleted one unused layout file `bar.xml`(100% sure not used) from my project, then tried to build a release, I got this error message:

```
app/src/main/res/layout/bottomsheet.xml:55: Error: @+id/button is not a sibling in the same ConstraintLayout [NotSibling]
Explanation for issues of type "NotSibling":
Layout constraints in a given ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout should
reference other views within the same relative layout (but not itself!)
```

the strange part is that I didn't do any changes to this file `bottomsheet.xml` and it had that constraint problem for ages without any error in release builds, my git status shows that I have deleted 1 file only `bar.xml`, fixing the `not sibling error` in `bottomsheet.xml` solved the problem and I was able to build, but also restoring the deleted `bar.xml` without changing anything in `bottomsheet.xml` solves it...

Note that I did `clean build`, `rebuild` and even `invalidate cache and restart` between those tests

Any idea what causes lint task `lintVitalAppRelease` to throw/ignore that error?

Comment: Hi friend please show your layout/bottomsheet.xml code this error because constraintlayout not at same parent

Comment: @adipurnama as I mentioned, I have solved the problem in the bottomsheet.xml, now it builds, my problem why it didn't do this before, even though the problem existed in the bottomsheet.xml and it was building

Comment: oh...sory for my miss understand,maybe this problem at refactor or build gradle version,I have experienced it, when deleting files with refactor